# Cual es la diferencia entre this y self en javascript

Tags: javascript

He visto que dentro de un metodo o una funcion en **`javascript`** hacen la referencia `this` con una variable `self`.

Comment: puedes agregar el ejemplo a tu duda, no sabemos si es orientado a objeto o simplemente una funcion

Comment: Falta indicar lo que has buscado/investigados sobre esto.

Comment: En inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this

Answer (score 4):

En javascript this, es dependiente del contexto en el cual se encuentra y va a ir cambiando de método en método ya que es dinámico.

La técnica de dejar this guardado en self se usa para tener siempre la referencia original al objeto que disparó ese método.

Puedes llegar a encontrar tambien variantes dependiendo de los gustos de los desarrolladores como:

```
var _this = this;
```

ó

```
var thiz = this;
```

ó

```
var me = this;
```

Lo intentaré ilustrar con un ejemplo. En el cual queremos usar this global en una función, e incluso en una función dentro de esa función.

```
function a(){
console.log(this); // este this no es el del handler es relativo a la funcion a

function b(){
console.log(this); // y este this tampoco es el del handler y tampoco es relativo a function a, este this es relativo a b
}

};
```

Entonces como hacemos para usar el this global dentro de estas funciones usamos la tecnica de self o _this es lo mismo, personalmente prefiero _this.

```
var _this = this;

function a(){
console.log(_this); // ahora si es el this del contexto global

 function b(){
  console.log(_this); // lo mismo aqui
 }

};
```